# Access to the parent element during instantiation

Tags: javascript

Let's consider the following code:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" class="form-control" id="foo">
<script>
function Bar(param1, param2) {
  this.param1 = param1;
  this.param2 = param2;
  // How to have access to the foo element here ?
}

let foo = document.getElementById('foo');
foo.bar = new Bar('something', 'something else');
</script>
```

Is there any way to access to the parent element (foo) inside the Bar function during the instantiation (without passing "foo" as a parameter) ?

Comment: What is the actual limitation? You could have a function `getFoo()` which you could invoke from the `Bar` constructor.

Comment: there is no direct way to access the parent element (`foo`) inside the `Bar` function during instantiation without passing it as a parameter. The `Bar` function does not have inherent knowledge of the parent element.

Comment: `foo` is not the parent element of anything. "Parent" means that it contains at least a child element but `<input>` is a type of element that does not have content, therefore it cannot have children.

Answer (score -2):

You are already setting `foo.bar` using `new Bar('something', 'something else')`, so you can use `this`

```
function Bar(param1, param2) {
  this.param1 = param1;
  this.param2 = param2;
  this.parentElement = document.getElementById('foo');
}

let foo = document.getElementById('foo');
foo.bar = new Bar('something', 'something else');
```